# Call knockout js function

Tags: knockout.js

I have a KnockoutJS model that has a function "getProgramDetails", this gets called upon a drop down list change event:

data-bind = "value: programId, event: {change: getProgramDetails}"

This works great, but how can I call this function on page load after i pass in the default program id of 1? Is there a way to call a function if the programId property changes? Instead of calling the function via the change event of the drop down list. That might help.

Here is my model:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var UploadModel = function (programId) {
    var self = this;
    self.programId = ko.observable(programId);
    self.fileType = ko.observable();
    self.fileTypes = ko.observableArray();
    self.getProgramDetails = function () {
        if (self.programId() > 0) {
            // get program budget level and file types
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetProgramDetails", "FileLoader")', 
                data: 'programId=' + self.programId(),
                dataType: 'json', 
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#budget-level').html(data.BudgetBalance);
                    var jsonFileTypes = data.FileTypes;

                    // add default option
                    jsonFileTypes.unshift({ 'Id': '', 'Name': '-- Select One --' });
                    self.fileTypes(jsonFileTypes);

                    $('.allow-upload').fadeIn();
                }
            });

        } else {
            $('.allow-upload').hide();
        }
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new UploadModel('1'), $('#container-upload')[0]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a manual subscription to a property like the programId in your example, and also want it to fire immediately, you can use a knockout computed observable.

The computed observable evaluates immediately, and every time any one of it's dependencies changes.

A lesser known fact is that Knockout even supports anonymous computed observables, which are very useful for situations like this.

```
var UploadModel = function (programId) {
  self.programId = ko.observable(programId);
  ...

  ko.computed(function(){
    // register programId as a dependency
    self.programId() 
    // execute the function you need to call
    self.getProgramDetails(); 
  });
};
```

[Knockout Computed Docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#controlling_dependencies_using_peek)

Comment: Wow, that's cool. I didn't know about that. I think I like your answer better. I did a simple jsFiddle to test it out using the console: http://jsfiddle.net/GQzPf/.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. To call a function when an observable changes, use `subscribe`:

```
self.programId.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    alert('Program ID is now:' + newValue);
}, self);
```

This is documented all the way at the bottom of [this page of the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).

I have found, however, that `subscribe` does not fire on the initial page load, even if you initialize your observable. You still have to do something like this:

```
var UploadModel = ...;
var theViewModel = new UploadModel('1');
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#container-upload')[0]);
theViewModel.getProgramDetails();
```

Comment: You need to _call_ the subscribe function to add a new listener, not _redefine_ it.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I messed that up.

Comment: Hey, no problem! You might want to check out the answer from @Gordon too. I like it because it's cleaner, and it seems like the recommended way to achieve the same end.

Comment: Thanks, I think you meant @Nathan I am Gordon :)

Comment: Yes, sorry! I meant Nathan.